# Exit graphical X session and getting back to TTY

Tags: xorg, tty

If I start a graphical session (usually Unity Desktop, sometimes XFCE, but a general approach is appreciated) from a TTY using `startx`, how can I exit this GUI again to get back to my TTY console without logging out?

I tried `pkill init` which seemed to do what I want, but is this the right way to go? Is the TTY session afterwards in an equal state to before `startx` or are there any traces left? And preferably the solution should not force running applications to terminate, but quit them gracefully...

---

**Edit:**

I started a Unity Desktop session with `startx $(which unity)` and then ran in a terminal emulator `gnome-session-quit` with all possible argument combinations, but it did nothing and always failed with the error message below:

```
** (gnome-session-quit:3968): WARNING **: Failed to call logout: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: 
The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: What session are you starting, specifically? some provide their own quit functions (such as `gnome-session-quit`)

Comment: @steeldriver In my case it would be mostly **Unity** or sometimes **XFCE**.

Comment: Well XFCE4 has `xfce4-session-logout`; I believe Unity is a `gnome-session`?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried `gnome-session-quit`, but it fails with the message in the question edit and does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

```
killall xinit
```

works ok. Not sure you're going to find a generic way to gracefully close all possible sessions.

For some reason if I start a unity session from TTY, and then run

```
unity
```

in a terminal, it seems to close it fairly gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I note you didn't say why you'd want to do this? Suggest using regular logout method, if you started with `startx` it should go back to character mapped text display.

If you still see the graphical login, and/or if you don't care to save changes or logout normally, or if something has crashed, sometimes I will run from the virtual tty `killall -u $(whoami)` which get things done rather fast. Looking forward to also trying `killall xinit` which sounds effective. Both are fairly brutal ways.

You can logout of graphical while keeping a terminal running with `tmux`. You need to start tmux before you realise the job is long mind.

I want a long running terminal app to keep running through my logout and terminate X11, I will go `ctrl-alt-f4` to login on the "black and white" screen, then `su` to myself (or another user if I wanna do killall user), then start a `tmux` session, then `ctrl-alt-f1` back to the GUI and go:

`tmux attach`

I can then alt-F4 this or logout and session is still there.